# Are there any Hindu cults/sects that have new scripture from the modern era?

Tags: scripture, kali-yuga

Is there any Hindu or Hindu adjacent cult that has modern era scripture? Like the Moonies have with the Divine Principle or even more scripture-like for a lack of a better term.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_Church.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. There are books written by popular gurus, or otherwise their teachings or biography was recorded by their disciples, and these books become a sort of modern era scripture for their followers.

Examples:

- The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna
- Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda
- Sri Sai Satcharitra (Shirdi Sai Baba)
- Autobiography of a Yogi (by Paramahansa Yogananda)
- Sathya Sai Speaks (volumes of discourses by Sathya Sai Baba)
- Inner Engineering: A Yogi's Guide to Joy (by Sadhguru Jaggi Vasudev)